# Play 2.0 on miniserver (pogoplug)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have got a pogoplug an want to run an play2.0 application on this device. Pogoplug has 128mb ram und a dualcore processor. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the OS and connectivity options?

I think the easiest way is to use `dist` command to prepare zipped application, push it to the server and start there. `start` and `stage` commands builds application from source and you probably don't want ot do that on 128m ram.

Of course you need JRE and play installed there and HTTP server in front.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question, but here are some things you should consider:

- remove any services that you don't absolutely need. Ideally, you will only have sshd and the web application itself running. Most linux distributions come with a lot of unnecessary stuff installed.
- Tune your jvm memory settings.
- Configure lots of swap space.
- Use an in-process database, for example h2.